# How to apply css from one file in UIBinder?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am working with gwt 2.3 UIbinder.In UIbider one apply css inline to gwt controls.Here is my UIBinderWidget.ui.xml file.

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
```

.important {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .grid
        {
            border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
            height: auto;
            padding: 3px;
        }

```
<g:>
<g:HTMLPanel>
Label,
    <g:Button styleName="{style.important}" ui:field="button" />
    <g:TextBox ui:field="text1" width="15em" />
    <g:Grid ui:field="grid1" styleName="{style.grid}">

        <g:row>
            <g:customCell>
                <g:TextBox ui:field="text2" width="15em" />
            </g:customCell>
            <g:customCell>
                <g:TextBox ui:field="text3" width="15em" />
            </g:customCell>
        </g:row>

        <g:row>
            <g:customCell>
                <g:Button ui:field="buttonA">Button A</g:Button>
            </g:customCell>
            <g:customCell>
                <g:Button ui:field="buttonB">Button B</g:Button>
            </g:customCell>
        </g:row>
        <g:row>
            <g:customCell>
                <g:Button ui:field="addNewRow">Add New Row</g:Button>
            </g:customCell>
        </g:row>
    </g:Grid>

</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Now in this xml file css which is applied to the gwt controls are in declared above.
I want to know it there any way to put all the css in only one file and I am able to apply css from that once css file only?

Instead of writing css in every ui.xml I want to apply from only one file. (Like style.css)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the `ui:style` like:

```
<ui:style src='path/to/my/css' />
```

But in general, I think that is a good practice to keep the HTML with the CSS altogether.

Comment: hey thanks for reply.but how to set path As I declared path by setting all type but still it is giving err CSS file uibinder/LoginPanel.css is missing.uibinder is war folder.

Comment: The path is relative to the folder where the uibinder file is. So use ../ to go up if necessary

Comment: BTW, the 'path/to/my/css' must point to a file that is reachable from the source path defined by your gwt.xml module.
Whatever is in your css will be 'compiled' by GWT and transformed into an obfuscated, minimized and optimized version.